# Why is my str_replace not working on short code submitted by front-end?

Tags: php, shortcode

I've built a front-end post submission form that allows a user to include a shortcode provided by SoundCloud. SoundCloud shortcodes generally look like this:

```
[soundcloud url="http://api.soundcloud.com/playlists/92355602" params="" width=" 100%" height="450" iframe="true" /]
```

The user pastes the shortcode into my form and my form receives the short code just fine. Before I save it as post meta on the post, I'm trying to perform a few str_replace functions on it.

```
if( isset( $_POST['scembed'] ) ) {
    $scembed = $_POST['scembed'];
    $scembed = str_replace( " 100%", "100%", $scembed );
    $scembed = str_replace( "params=\"\"", "params=\"show_artwork=false\"", $scembed );
    $scembed = str_replace( "height=\"450\"", "height=\"405\"", $scembed );
}
```

The first one works because it's just removing the erroneous space in the string. But then the next two, I actually need to include the attribute and its double quotes to accurately target the string to change.

It won't work and I'm not sure why. I even tried this:

```
$pfind = 'params=""';
$preplace = 'params="show_artwork=false"';
$scembed = str_replace( $pfind, $preplace, $scembed );
```

What am I missing? Any time you include the double quotes for the attributes, the function is ignored :-/

-- For Ravs -------------------

```
<form name="create_post" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="scembed" maxlength="160" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>

if( !empty( $_POST ) ) {
  if( !empty( $_POST['scembed'] ) ) {
      $scsource = $_POST['scembed'];
    $searchReplaceArray = array(
      ' 100%' => '100%', 
      'params=""' => 'params="show_artwork=false"',
      'height="450"' => 'height="405"',
    );
    $scembed = str_replace( array_keys( $searchReplaceArray ), array_values( $searchReplaceArray ), $scsource );
  }
}

if( $scembed )
  add_post_meta( $post_id, 'scembed', $scembed, TRUE );
```

Comment: what output you are getting ? function seems to work fine.

Comment: The output which gets stored in my post_meta is this:

`[soundcloud url="http://api.soundcloud.com/playlists/92355602" params="" width="100%" height="450" iframe="true" /]`

The only thing that changes is the space before 100% which is the first str_replace I execute. The other two never seem to work.

Comment: can you paste you whole function code in question that do this functionality?

Comment: There are well over 350 lines of code in this form/processing function but I pasted the parts where this data is at play.

I have now tried a short code without the [ and ] still didn't work which may rule out WordPress thinking it's a short code and preventing something.

The new code I pasted for Ravs doesn't work either. It *will* remove the leading 0 from the 100% but will NOT change the other two.

Comment: P.S. I also changed the field from a textarea to a text input and that had no effect either.

Comment: Have you tried echoing or logging the value of `$_POST['scembed']` before you get started with replacing, to see what is actually in it?  My guess is that the value has some escaping or encoding of its own already in the string before you get it.  For example, the string might actually have `params=\"\"` in it or maybe even `params=&quot;&quot;`.

Comment: Yep that's what it was Ben. I actually did try the &quot; scenario, but didn't think that maybe the data had already been escaped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to put this code before replace text in string

inside `if( !empty( $_POST['scembed'] ) ) {`

```
$_POST['scembed'] = stripslashes( $_POST['scembed'] );
```

**Note**

problem occuring because your quote are escaped in string, so " becomes \"

Comment: Ravs you're right... in a weird scenario where I was testing something else, my form data was returned to the screen and I could then see the quotes had already been escaped! Thanks for your help and solution.